# Displaying the values of an n-dimension array as a string

Tags: arrays, c, string, recursion, multidimensional-array

Provided that we have an integer array of arbitrary depth, how would we traverse through it in order to build a string that represents the array as a C-style initialization?

For instance:

```c
int arr3D[2][3][2]  = { {{0, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}}, {{6, 7}, {8, 9}, {10, 11}} };
```

We only know:

- the total number of values (in this case 12)
- the number of "dimensions" (in this case 3)
- each of the dimension indexes (in this case 2,3,2)
- the values `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11`

How can we make a string out of that, that looks like this:
`"{{{0,1},{2,3},{4,5}},{{6,7},{8,9},{10,11}}}"` ?

---

Evidently, this can be done with a nested nested loop, but that would only work with a definite set of dimensions (3). What if we have 10 dimensions? That made me think I can use recursion, but then it became confusing when and how to put `{` `}` characters. I am currently thinking about a single linear scan that intelligently inserts `{` and `}` characters in the string `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11` but I feel like the real-world approach would be something like an indefinite n-tree branch traversing algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned there are no need for the ndim nested `for` loops; what you could do is to use concepts like *stride*. Like then in how many count you change a dimension and then you can build you string.

Since you have not written any example code, I will write pseudo code to show how this could be done. In final case, dimensions should be input and stride calculated dynamically. Also, it is better to build a string and print it at the end, but for exposition, I'll output character by character using `printf()`.

```
void print_mat(int* ptr, int ndims, int* dims){
    int *stride = malloc(sizeof(int)* ndims);  // TODO: null check
    // create stride array same size of dims
    stride[ndims -1] = dims[ndims - 1];
    for(int j = ndims - 2 ; j >= 0; j--)
        stride[j] = dims[j] * stride[j + 1];
    // loop over all elements, stride[0] has the length
    for(int idx = 0 ; idx < stride[0]; idx++){
        // print open { for each start dimension
        for(int i = 0; i < ndims; i++)
            if (idx % stride[i] == 0){printf("{");}

        printf("%d", ptr[idx]);
        // print close } for each end dimension
        for(int i = 0; i < ndims; i++)
            if ((idx + 1) % stride[ndims - i - 1] == 0){printf("}");}

        printf(", "); // comma after each element
    }
    printf("\b\b \n"); // clear extra , at end (may not support in all terminals)
    free(stride);
}

int main()
{
    int arr3D[2][3][2]  = { {{0, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}}, {{6, 7}, {8, 9}, {10, 11}} };
    int dims[3] = {2, 3, 2};
    print_mat(&arr3D[0][0][0], 3, dims);
    // same as 
    // print_mat((int *) arr3D, 3, dims);
    return 0;

}
```

This produces the desired output:

```
{{{0, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}}, {{6, 7}, {8, 9}, {10, 11}}}
```

Comment: Is the stride calculated as dimension_index * the multiplication of the rest dimension indices?

Comment: @yes like cumulative prod , should be linear time, start from last dimension. 
2, 2x3, 6x2

Comment: That was my implementation of the function to create the stride https://hastebin.com/axozuwahej.c

Comment: Sure, looks good to me. Btw, slightly cleaned my answer plus comment,